# wget-like bittorrent client or library?

Tags: linux, bittorrent

Is there any bittorrent client or (Java|Python|Ruby|Perl) library that I can use like wget or curl?

I would like to use simply as a step in a script, like you would use wget.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: There is question about ubuntu bittorrent command line client at ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29872/torrent-client-for-the-command-line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ctorrent

```
 SYNOPSIS
        ctorrent [General Options]  [Download Options]  [Make Torrent
 Options] file.torrent

        CTorrent   is  a  BitTorrent  Client  written in C that doesn’t
 require any graphical component, such as an X server.  It’s built as a
 console program and it can be even used remotely in a machine that
 provides outside ssh access.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can load torrents in rtorrent from the command line.

wget terminates after a download. You can add the exit command to the on_finished event in your .rtorrent.rc.

If you need to run the application in the background, you can use the screen management utility, or the & operator.

If you want to watch the file download, you would simply omit the screen management.

Another solution is to get rtorrent to watch a directory for torrents. When a download is complete, you can specify which directory it will get moved to. To start a download, you move your file into the watch directory with your script, and check for its completion status by checking the "completed" directory for files.

Answer (score 4):

btdownloadheadless

```
SYNOPSIS
       btdownloadheadless [ option ... ] URL
       btdownloadheadless [ option ... ] filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the official "BitTorrent" client (prior to version 6, of course) from bittorrent.com. It contains both a console and a curses version. It's usually called the `bittorrent` package (instead of the `bittorrent-gui` package, which is the GUI version) in various Linux distros. The latest for Linux is 5.x, although Ubuntu/Debian only has 3.x. Run `bittorrent-console` or `bittorrent-curses` for the console and curses versions, respectively (on 4.x and 5.x); or `btdownloadheadless.bittorrent` or `btdownloadcurses.bittorrent` (on 3.x).

Answer (score 1):

I always use transmission-cli and most Linux distros split the transmission-cli which is the command line interface and the gui portion up. Another one I can suggest is Lftp although I found that it's not working for some sites.

Answer (score 0):

I've used btdownloadheadless from the bittornado package as suggested by gnibbler.  I also recommend using screen with btdownloadcurses for a nice display of progress, etc., that you can easily background.