# Perl library for simple torrent downloading?

Tags: perl, bittorrent

I am in need of a library for perl that will let me download files from torrents and magnet links in a simple way. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several such libraries include:

- [Net::BitTorrent](http://code.google.com/p/net-bittorrent/) or [here](http://search.cpan.org/~sanko/Net-BitTorrent-0.052/lib/Net/BitTorrent.pm) , with documentation [here](http://search.cpan.org/~sanko/Net-BitTorrent-0.052/lib/Net/BitTorrent/Notes.pod)
- [Protocol::BitTorrent](http://search.cpan.org/~team/Protocol-BitTorrent-0.003/lib/Protocol/BitTorrent.pm)

Several existing Perl BitTorent clients include:

- [Bitflu](http://bitflu.workaround.ch/)
- [AnyEvent::BitTorrent](http://search.cpan.org/~sanko/AnyEvent-BitTorrent-v0.1.5/lib/AnyEvent/BitTorrent.pm)
- [Basic Net::BitTorrent Client](http://search.cpan.org/~sanko/Net-BitTorrent-0.052/tatoeba/000-basic.pl)

Also see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570750/wget-like-bittorrent-client-or-library).